# Why is this instance of a class being converted to a regular object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making an app with WebSockets in Node.js. In order to run certain things asynchronously, I wrapped some async code in an async function and then ran it.

However, the issue is that whenever this portion is ran, the code throws an error that `call.createTransport` is not a function. This function is clearly defined in the Call class and works when I call it outside of this context.

I proceeded to log the call and found that before running the async function, the call object was an instance of Call, but inside the async function it is a regular JavaScript object, with the properties but not the methods defined.

I am completely stuck on this issue. I am running Node.js 16 LTS.

```js
(async (call, produce, consume) => {
    let sendTransport;
    if (produce) {
        sendTransport = await call.createTransport();
    }
    let receiveTransport;
    if (consume) {
        receiveTransport = await call.createTransport();
    }
    return { sendTransport, receiveTransport };
})(client.call, produce, consume).then(({ sendTransport, receiveTransport }) => {
    callClients.set(sId, {
        ...client,
        produce: true,
        sendTransport,
        receiveTransport
    });
    s.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: CallEventType.TRANSPORT,
        data: {
            sendTransport,
            receiveTransport
        }
    }));
});
```

Comment: Without additional information it’s difficult to help—function parameters are what they are at the time of the call. It’s more likely there’s an incorrect assumption being made, but it’s impossible to know what it might be with the provided snippet.

Comment: @DaveNewton How should I go about debugging this issue? I have no clue how Node.js is converting this Call object into a regular object and it only occurs inside this function. What additional information do I need for you to better understand/help?

Comment: For the SO question: include the relevant portions of the class in question, e.g., the class declaration itself, the shell of the `createTransport` function so it's clear how it's defined, how `client.call` relates to the instance of the class in question, etc. As it stands there's no context here.

Comment: For the debugging: check every single one of your assumptions. Node does not randomly change references or the values they refer to; that would break everything. Break the problem down into smaller chunks, e.g., create a wee function that takes a single parameter and returns a reference. Try it with an explicit `new` of the class in question instead of an indirect reference. Build it up until it breaks, then take a step back and see why it broke.

Comment: Problem solved... it was due to another arbitrary function in another file.